# "Could not find the module Az.Accounts with given version" error when running Azure DevOps job in Docker

Tags: powershell, docker, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I install PowerShell and Az module in container based on ubuntu:16.04

```
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - && \
    wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb && \
    dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb && \
    apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install powershell -y && \
    pwsh -c "Install-Module -Name Az -Force"
```

It works fine when I ssh to Docker running on my machine,
..but fails with error "Could not find the module Az.Accounts with given version" when executed in Azure DevOps pipeline:
[image]

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: `Install-Module -Name Az.Resources -Scope CurrentUser -Force`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What version of Az.Accounts is being loaded? If it is 2.0.0-preview the DevOps task will fail.

You can check for it using `Get-InstalledModule Az.Accounts -AllVersions`

If it is the case use:

`Uninstall-Module -Name Az.Accounts -RequiredVersion 2.0.0-preview -AllowPrerelease`

to remove the preview then add the current version:

`Install-Module -Name Az.Accounts -RequiredVersion 1.7.0`

I have no idea why the preview gets installed but it has plagued me for a while...

Answer (score 0):

The document [Install the Azure PowerShell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-3.3.0#install-the-azure-powershell-module-1) warns below:

> You can't have both the AzureRM and Az modules installed for PowerShell 5.1 for Windows at the same time. If you need to keep AzureRM available on your system, install the Az module for PowerShell Core 6.x or later. To do this, install PowerShell Core 6.x or later and then follow these instructions in a PowerShell Core terminal.

It will cause problem if AzureRM an Az Modules are both installed.

You can have a try to use azure powershell v4 or v3 task as discussed in [this thread](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/3869).

You can also have a try to run below script to uninstall AzureRM. For details please check out the detailed scripts in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55411029/azure-powershell-az-module-not-working-on-ubuntu-hosted-build-agent)

`Uninstall-Module -Name AzureRM -AllVersions`

Comment: Hi @kagarlickij Did you try out above reply, How was it going? Please let me know if there is any question.