# Azure Pipeline: On task success or fail, run failure-related tasks. If failed, stop pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Take not of the following `azure-pipelines.yml` file:

```
trigger:
  - main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
    - script: ./e2e.sh
      displayName: Run Integration Tests
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: Publish e2e test videos
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: 'app/cypress/videos'
        ArtifactName: Videos
        publishLocation: 'Container'
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: Publish Web Static Artifact
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: 'app/dist/web'
        ArtifactName: Web
        publishLocation: 'Container'
```

The order should be:

```
A. Run Integration Tests
if (A.fail || A.succeed) {
  B. Publish e2e test videos
}
if (A.fail) {
  exit pipeline
}
C. Publish Web Static Artifact
```

I am aware that I can use `condition`, so the key question is how to:

- capture whether task A failed
- stop the pipeline

How do I achieve this?

Comment: So - `B` should be run always and `C` only if `A` passed?

Comment: Correct, but `B` and `C` should strictly run after `A`

Comment: there are other tasks in the pipeline or only those 3?

Comment: There are other tasks before and after

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60819191/task-control-option-custom-condition-run-task-when-previous-failed-or-timed