"Could not find the modules: 'Az.Accounts' with Version" error while running AzurePowershell@5 task
I am using AzurePowershell@5 task to run a powershell script that will build the template specs and push it to resource group. I am using azurerm service connection for authentication. Here is task details :
 
- task: AzurePowershell@5
            displayName: Template Spec Generation
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'azurerm service principal'
              scriptType: filePath
              scriptPath: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\src\sxript.ps1
              scriptArguments:
                -resourceGroupName <name> `
                -location eastus `
                -overrideVersion true `
                -isTagged true `
                -tag test `
                -outputPath output.json
              azurePowerShellVersion: latestVersion
              pwsh: true

But I am getting following error while running this task:

##[error]Could not find the modules: 'Az.Accounts' with Version: ''. If the module was recently installed, retry after restarting the Azure
Pipelines task agent.
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.

Can someone please help here?

Is the Az module installed? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-azure-powershell?view=azps-11.4.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-7.2.0

What kind of Agent are you using? Microsoft-Hosted agent or Self-hosted agent?

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59681516/could-not-find-the-module-az-accounts-with-given-version-error-when-running-az

You need to install the module and then import it as part of your script, but the should be separate tasks.
- pwsh: |
    Install-Module -Name Az.Accounts -Scope CurrentUser -AllowClobber -Force

and then to your script add
Import-Module Az.Accounts

You don't NEED to add this to your Docker image if you are self hosting but it would be beneficial instead of installing it every time, also you don't need to restart the container/agent.

I can reproduce the same issue when I use the Self-hosted Agent.

The cause of the issue could be that the Az module hasn't been install on the agent machine.
To solve this issue, you need to navigate to the machine where the agent located and run the following command to install the Az module.
Install-Module -Name Az -Scope AllUsers -AllowClobber

Then you can restart the self-hosted agent and run the Pipeline again.
For Microsoft-hosted Agent, the Az module has been pre-installed on the Agent machine. You can run the command: Get-Module Az -ListAvailable to check the modules installed in Microsot-hosted Agent.

The Az.Accounts module is not installed, or outdated in your self-hosted agent. Hosted agent are updated by Microsoft.
A fix with Install-Module -Name Az.Accounts and then Import-Module Az.Accounts in the same pipeline is not possible, I tried that and it won't work, possibly because of this issue with -ListAvailable in VstsAzureHelpers_ Utility 
    try {
        if ($authScheme -eq 'ServicePrincipal') {
            Write-Verbose "Trying to disconnect from Azure and clear context at process scope"

            if (Get-Module Az.Accounts -ListAvailable) {
                Disconnect-UsingAzModule -restrictContext $restrictContext
            }
            else {
                if ($featureFlags.retireAzureRM) {
                    Write-Error "Unable to get Az.Accounts module in Disconnect-AzureAndClearContext"
                } else {
                    Disconnect-UsingARMModule
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        $message = $_.Exception.Message
        Write-Verbose "Unable to disconnect and clear context: $message"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=warning;]$message"
    }

With a self-hosted agent you could install the required/allowed modules beforehand in their Dockerfile:
RUN pwsh -c "Install-Module -Name Az.Accounts -AllowClobber -Scope AllUsers -Force"

